# Maven build no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, maven

I'm building a small app with Maven that has dependencies and is an executable jar file.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>site-downloader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.siteripper</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-interfaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.company.Main
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The build completes with no issues but when executing the jar it writes

> no main manifest attribute, in *local maven repo* / *my jar*.

I sought aid at the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) and [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) too to no avail.

I seek assistance to make the jar include its dependencies and is executable at the same time.

**Edit:**

I updated my `pom` to use the jar and the dependencies plugins instead of the assembly. Here is the updated pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>site-downloader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.siteripper</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-interfaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.company.Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when running it:

> C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Commands>call java -jar
>   D:.m2\repository\com\company\site-downloader\1.0.0\site-downloader-1.0.0.jar
>   -9gag https://9gag.com/gag/arGEvRX?ref C:\Users\myusername\Documents\sites\data\android Error: A JNI error
>   has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception
>   in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 7 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved your issue:
Please ignore business logic, 
since I am using MongoDB, added MongoDB driver as a dependency and able to run with java -jar command.
The end goal is same as of yours.
I am using maven-shade plug-in.

Checkout project from [Github source code:](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/platform/blob/master/test.zip)
unzip, build, test
OR
1. Created a maven project
`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4`

2. Update pom.xml with following, added mongo client code from OP and printing collection names
3. Execute 
   `mvn clean package`
4. Execute
   `java -jar test.jar`
   output I got is:

```
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:9}] to localhost:27017
Jun 01, 2019 8:17:22 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2249770}
Jun 01, 2019 8:17:22 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:10}] to localhost:27017
admin
config
local
test
[XenonSuite] Successfully connected to MongoDB
```

**pom.xml**(ignore package names)
Check **shade plugin configuration**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
  </properties>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
                  </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

There are multiple ways to solve this problem
Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: When checking out `test` and initiating a `mvn clean install` I get a successful build, but when I run the jar file with `java -jar test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get a no manifest problem. Shall I reinstall my maven?

Comment: no, you need to run `mvn clean package` as mention in answer, if you want jar to be used in install phase, change `<phase>package</phase>` to `<phase>install</phase>`, also you are executing wrong jar file, correct one is with test.jar in same path, execute `java -jar test.jar`

Comment: Sorry, I stopped reading at `OR`. Indeed it works with the `test.jar`. What I do not get is, why does it generate a `test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` too and why does that jar give me the no main manifest attribute?

Comment: the reason is `test.jar` is created by shaded plugin and have menifest file created. which is not the case with `test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: And can we set maven up not to create the snapshot jar? :D

Answer (score 3):

To create an executable jar, you have to use the following maven jar plugin. I provide below the code snippet.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                your main class
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

For more details, refer below the github link to get an idea of how to create executable/runnable jar.

https://github.com/debjava/runnableJar

> As per docs, Maven Assembly Plugin for Maven is primarily intended to
>   allow users to aggregate the project output along with its
>   dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files into a
>   single distributable archive.

Refer below the details of Maven Assembly plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, will try it out right now. But shouldn't the assembly plugin work too? 
AFAIK the assembly plugin copies the dependencies into a single jar (package - single in my pom) and makes it executable too.

Comment: Hi @agiro, I have updated the answer about maven assembly plugin.

Comment: After the jar plugin I added the dependencies plugin too https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html and this time it starts but fails with `NoClassDefFoundError` for one of my dependencies, `Selenium`. 
I removed my old assembly plugin of course.

Comment: Sure, I update the question with the new pom and the error.